# constexpr for values passed in by reference

Tags: c++, constexpr, std-bitset

I had this piece of code which compiles

```
#include <bitset>

struct A{
    std::bitset<50> b; };

void test(A a){
    static_assert(sizeof(int)*8 < a.b.size(), "can't accomodate int in bitset");
    int x = 5;
    a.b = x; }

int main(){
    A a;
    test(a); }
```

But this doesn't

```
#include <bitset>

struct A{
    std::bitset<50> b;
};

void test(A& a){
    static_assert(sizeof(int)*8 < a.b.size(), "can't accomodate int in bitset");
    int x = 5;
    a.b = x;
}

int main(){
    A a;
    test(a);
}
```

Fails with this error

```
const.cpp: In function ‘void test(A&)’: const.cpp:8:5: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
     static_assert(sizeof(int)*8 < a.b.size(), "can't accomodate int in bitset");
const.cpp:8:5: error: ‘a’ is not a constant expression
```

Why is `a.b.size()` not treated as a constexpr in the second case? Isn't the `constexpr` for `std::bitset::size()` the one that should be treated as const as per the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/size)? Or does the non-const reference passed in the second case trigger the compiler to generate the error?

Compiler version:
g++ 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.0.4, compiled with `g++ const.cpp -std=c++1y`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

| Deprecation Notice |
| --- |
| This answer is now obsolete due to the changes in [P2280: Using unknown pointers and references in constant expressions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2280r4.html) (proposal accepted into C++23 and applied as a defect report to C++11). GCC 14 and more recent compilers accept the original code as valid. See https://godbolt.org/z/KE5G969ca. |

`A& a` is not *usable in constant expressions*, making your program ill-formed.

The rule forbidding `a.b.size()` to be a constant expression with `a` being a `A&` is the following:

> #### [`[expr.const]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#3)
>
> A variable is *usable in constant expressions* after its initializing declaration is encountered if it is a constexpr variable, or it is of reference type or of const-qualified integral or enumeration type, and its initializer is a constant initializer.

In your case, the variable `a` is:

- not declared `constexpr` (as a function argument, it wouldn't make sense),
- and is not an integral or enumeration type,
- and is not a reference whose initialization is a constant initializer:

> #### [`[expr.const]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2)
>
> A *constant initializer* for a variable or temporary object `o` is an initializer for which interpreting its full-expression as a *constant-expression* results in a constant expression, except that if `o` is an object, such an initializer may also invoke constexpr constructors for `o` and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types.

---

Take the following reduced example:

```
struct s { constexpr static bool true_value() { return true; } };
void assert_on(s const& ref)
{
    static_assert(ref.true_value());
}

int main()
{
    assert_on(s{});
}
```

gcc-9 wrongly accepts it<sup>1</sup>, but clang-8 produce the right diagnostic:

> ```
> error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
> ```

Full demo: https://godbolt.org/z/t_-Ubj

---

<sup>1)</sup> This is [GCC bug #66477](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66477), active from version 5.1 and yet to be resolved.

Comment: So, then is there a way to achieve what I intended to do i.e statically check whether the bitset member of the passed in variable(by ref) is enough to accommodate the integer?

Comment: This is half the answer, the other half is http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.12

Answer (score 2):

<s>With pointers from others<sup>1</sup>, it appears to be a compiler bug in both gcc and clang. It's fixed in gcc 5.1 but is, as of 2019-07-25, still a bug in clang 8.0</s>

This is a bug of gcc, introduced in version 5.1. See other answer.

---

<sup>1)</sup>

> Seems to be a (now fixed) compiler bug as it complies with the latest gcc version: https://godbolt.org/z/ZaDXED

Comment: Is it possible that it's a gcc's bug, clang is correct?

Comment: @songyuanyao Clang isn't the only one complaining. See e.g. [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7ORbU3).

Comment: @songyuanyao after reading it more carefully, I'm convinced. See other answer.