# C++ `constexpr` member functions on arguments passed by (const) reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, constexpr

Does anyone know if changes in the C++ standard might be in the works to allow calling `constexpr` member functions on arguments passed by (const) reference? Currently, that only works on args passed-by-value.

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/jW8YET3Ma

See one explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198203/380252 ...although probably obsolete, some of what's being said there doesn't really apply (anymore). The example above compiles with some (older) compilers, but that was apparently a bug.

I'm less interested in explanations for why that is happening and more in whether some of these `constexpr` restrictions would be relaxed. Restrictions that seem counter-intuitive (and counter-productive, since they're forcing the caller to pass-by-value, which is expensive).

There are some proposals; e.g., https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2242r3.html, but not clear if that would fix this.

Comment: Yes, your code is well-formed since C++23 due to [P2280: Using unknown pointers and references in constant expressions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2280r4.html). It used to be ill-formed because evaluating a reference in itself could be ill-formed (without any access taking place), but this was dumb and arbitrary and has been fixed.